# SQL get value from key in dictionary

Tags: mysql, sql, key

I have a column in my database which is called `user_log`. It basically logs everything a user does on the page. I use MySQL.

It looks like that:

| user_id | user_log |
| --- | --- |
| 1028 | { "last_login":"2022-04-08 12:03:05", "blog_entry_at":"2022-04-08 12:43:12" } |

Now, I want to extract all **`"last_login"`** and get the value of it.
It is a `text` field, but not a `dict` or something else

Comment: please specify RDBMS you use. This field looks like JSON and each RDBMS has its own way to handle it

Comment: Hey Sergey, I use MySQL, is that an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use json_extract in MySQL.
`SELECT user_id, json_extract(user_log, '$.last_login') as last_login FROM users;`

Sample query: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3y8a3brhr

More on json_extract here in the mariadb docs: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_extract/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [**`JSON_VALUE()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-value) function provided that the DB is of version `8.0.21+` such as

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(user_log, '$.last_login') AS extracted_value
  FROM t
```